# Replace entire phrase-Replace in string- Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I would like to replace the whole phrase in a field. I am working in pentaho.

For instance:

Replace the next phrase : "Good Morning everybody" for this one: "Hello", using the function "replace in a string".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et410.png)

However when I use the function I get the next result : "Hello everybody"

But I am expecting to get just the next word "Hello" .
How could do I it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the image attached, the value you're searching for and replacing is "Good Morning". That's why you receive that result. Just replace "Good Morning" with "Good Morning everybody" in field "Search" and you should have the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to that but first do a look up of key words and then replace the match string with a new one?

Example:

let say that i have the following different strings with text each on multiple rows of column called Event message:

1 - "the xxx database is down"

2 - "the pluggable database is down "

3 - "database is down"

etc

they all have in common 2 key works - "database" and "down"

i want to replace or that string or create a new column with a new string: "Database Down"

thank you for the help

Comment: This isn't an answer, it is a question asked as an answer. It's better to ask your own question, you can reference this question in your own.